# How to convert blob_image to clob_image?

Tags: oracle, plsql

**Under the code is not relation to image.**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blob_to_clob (blob_in IN BLOB)
    RETURN CLOB
    AS
    v_clob CLOB;
    v_varchar VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_start PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    v_buffer PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
    BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_clob, TRUE);

   FOR i IN 1..CEIL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_in) / v_buffer)
    LOOP

--**This code convert to blob**

    v_varchar := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(blob_in, v_buffer, v_start));`

    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob, LENGTH(v_varchar), v_varchar);`

--**Change the byte**

    v_start := v_start + v_buffer;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN v_clob;
    END blob_to_clob;`
```

Comment: Image is binary data why do you want to convert into text data ?

Comment: @jaraisyn: what's your question?

Comment: the code looks like the answer already. is it malfunctioning? if you're dealing with character data stored in a BLOB, the main question will be about consistent encoding

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz as you know we can store image jpg in clob and blob. This is example of text data, and how willdo with image data. So i have a blob of image and i need to convert it to clob in order to like make history(who change the data smt like this)

Comment: @Codo as you know we can store image jpg in clob and blob. This is example of text data, and how willdo with image data. So i have a blob of image and i need to convert it to clob in order to like make history(who change the data smt like this)

Comment: @dlatikay as you know we can store image jpg in clob and blob. This is example of text data, and how willdo with image data. So i have a blob of image and i need to convert it to clob in order to like make history(who change the data smt like this)

Comment: sorry this makes it less clear, not more. what do you really want to achieve here? a transcription of the picture bytestream as character data, something like base-64 encoded, or am I missing something obvious here? and history? like picture difference, or a changelog?